# Why do some Internet service providers require special equipment?

Tags: networking, internet, modem, isp

I am trying to set up Internet at a new place with AT&T (U.S.). The online process requires me to pay $10 per month for a thingy they call "WiFi gateway" which they claim serves as "both a modem and a router". There is no option to skip it or un-check the box.

Searching for answers online I saw some posts claiming that "10 bucks isn't for the router, its not even for the modem - its for the Fiber to Ethernet converter box that you cannot buy. That's why even if you have your own compatible modem/router they can still charge you the $10."

Why does AT&T require this while other ISPs I have used do not? What exactly is it? How is it different from an ordinary modem (or modem/router combo)? If I don't want to pay that $10 can I just get a modem with an ONT port?

Comment: it is likely that you could find a third party device that would work as a modem for their network, but the most critical thing from their perspective is the ability to provision the device connection, and tie in their service and billing systems. Billing and Service codes define how automatic entitlement works on their network.

Comment: Taxing you for the Media Converter (Fiber to Ethernet box) is a scam. They should not do it. The wireless modem / router should be entirely optional. An ISP's obligation is to give you internet connection to the device you want. Let's say you want that for a PC. They must give you a working Ethernet connection (PPPoE or MAC-based access). With that, you can install your own router if you desire so. There should be no obligation to get theirs and no extra costs for something that is part of the ISP's infrastructure (the Media Converter).

Comment: It's called capitalism.  They are selling a service, and can charge whatever the market will bear (unless you are in a locale where it's still a regulated utility).

Comment: @sawdust It's called fraud, and despite the disgustingly prevalent correlation between profiteering and capitalism, last I checked it still isn't legal to blatantly lie in order to exploit someone for economically-motivated gain (not that that'll discourage your ISP from trying).

Comment: OP, you're not the only one, see [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502292/can-your-isp-really-control-whether-your-internet-signal-works-wirelessly-or-not), different ISP but basically the same tactic except they even decided to *start* billing me without prior notice when I already provided my own equipment from the onset.

Comment: You can vote with your wallet. Go somewhere else. If they can charge you they will charge you - that's how it goes. If there's no legislation to stop them doing it, they will. Suck it up or choose another company… or see how far you can get with it in court - that's how legislation gets changed.

Answer (score 1):

The "Wifi Gateway" charge is the rental fee for their equipment. You can use your own modem / router but you must make sure it is compatible with AT&t internet service first. To use your own equipment you will need to set up service over the phone, not online. This way they can register your device. This will bypass the $10 charge.

Comment: Note that — at least with Charter Spectrum — I initially setup service with my own equipment (checked and they were on the compatibility list), and confirmed I wasn't being billed it.  There was a period of time when I wasn't paying attention and they had without any prior notice started adding the charge to my bill again.  When I called to contest it, I was given the bogus answer linked in my comments to OP.